# Where can I find more lore behind Ashe and Tryndamere?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have learned that Ashe and Tryndamere got married to bring their two tribes together in the limited lore that I was able to find. I am interested in learning why they needed to bring their tribes together and why Sejuani was against the joining of the tribes? Are there any place that offers additional lore that I can read?

A wiki page or a specific journal of justice to read?

Comment: Similar in nature to other questions.  Riot as a company have not really gotten into the background to greatly with any of the lore.  The lore is just a little fun short story explaining why the champion is in Summoner's Rift.  Anything that isn't in the lore that you read is left to the player's imagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, the marriage was mostly out of political necessity and without actual love. I don't have much more info than that off the top of my head, but for more info on the lore of League of Legends you can always check out the wiki (http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/League_of_Legends_Wiki).

Answer (score 3):

You can try this site for the normal lore of these character's and would also include some guides if scrolled down if you are interested. If you haven't already read their lores then I'm sorry I couldn't be of more help.
http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/champion/ashe-13
http://www.mobafire.com/league-of-legends/champion/tryndamere-14

Answer (score 1):

You can find the lore of the league [here](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/learn/lore).
There is also a 'newspaper' or sorts within the client (Thanks to origional poster, it is called the journal of justice I think.  It is the feather just under the riots points total in upper right) but now that I think about it I have not seen an alert for a new issue in a little while.  You can also find on each champions page more specific lore for that particular champion.

In specific to Sequani the journal will not provide any information it has not been updated since her release.  Sequani in her lore if you read though views peace as a violation of the traditions of Freiljord (in specific to ashe's campaign for peace and joining the league).  I do not have specifics for the marriage and uniting the tribes off the top of my head but given the information in her lore it is because she views the peace as a slap in the face to tradition again.

Comment: Also, www.Fanfiction.net might be worth looking into as well. :P

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of a 'cannon' answer, fanfiction.net is not limited to cannon :p

Answer (score 0):

This answered all my questions about the topic XD

http://swan2swan.tumblr.com/post/45041799633/why-ashe-is-a-pure-example-of-female-power-and-you

Comment: Generally it's best to post a summery of what's contained within in a link, in case the link changes in future and makes your answer invalid :)